# C++: Sublime Text 2 and MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, sublimetext2

I need some help configuring Sublime Text 2 with MinGW. All I did was add MinGW to my path variable. I've been having some issues however.  for example, this code won't even pause to ask the user for input and immediately puts `cin` into a failed state.

```
    int input = 0;
    cin >> input;
```

It is not a problem with my code either, because I tested it with eclipse and it works fine. What else do I need to get Sublime Text 2 to work with MinGW?

Also, if it would be easier, I'm open to a new compiler.

Comment: Sublime Text is a text editor, not an IDE. Try compiling and running your program with a command prompt. (I can give you more information if needed.) There are ways you can ease the process by using the ST2 build system feature and clang plugin, but it's better to understand what's going on under the hood before expecting them to turn Sublime Text into an IDE of sorts.

Comment: thanks, some more info on how to compile and run from cmd would help. I've really gotten used to just hitting run with eclipse (bad, I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text is an advanced text editor, not an IDE. As requested, here are some instructions for compiling and running a program written with Sublime Text.

Launch a command prompt (press windows-key+R, type `cmd`, and press enter) and verify that the MinGW bin folder is in your path with `g++ --version`. If a version is returned, navigate to the location of your C++ source files with the `cd` command. For example, `cd "C:\Users\abaratham\Dev\test"`. Then compile the source files with `g++ -o myprogram.exe main.cpp othersource.cpp ...`.

If the build is successful, you should see a new myprogram.exe file in the project folder. If it's a command line program, you can run it in the same console with `myprogram`.

As you begin to develop software with many C++ source files, you might find it useful to use a high level build system such as CMake or SCons. Whichever you chose, you'll be able to generate makefiles and compile your project with `mingw32-make`.

Comment: You lost me at: Then compile the source files with g++ -o myprogram.exe main.cpp othersource.cpp ....

Comment: You should type that into your terminal, replace "myprogram" with the desired name of the executable, and follow it with the names of all the .cpp files you would like to compile into the target.

Comment: alright thanks alot, it worked great. Will I have to do this with everything I write? or is there an easier way to do this with Sublime Text 2?

Comment: and by the way, Sublime Text compiles it fine, just doesn't run it correctly.

Comment: Yes, Sublime Text can automate this task. Although, I don't think it automatically runs the program upon build. You can leave the terminal open to manually run after building though.